# Tar a list of files if they exist

Tags: bash

I have a list of files that may or maynot exist that I need to compress and pack using tar as part of a bigger script. Currently I have,

```
tar -czvf config.tar.gz file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml
```

The problem is not all of the files might exist, and this would give an error if they didn't. What is the best way to check and pack the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=("$@")
for i in "${!files[@]}"
do
    [ -e "${files[i]}" ] || unset files[i]
done
tar -czvf config.tar.gz "${files[@]}"
```

To use it:

```
script  file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml
```

In this way, the tar.gz file is created in one step without storing intermediate files on disk.

#### Alternative: a shell function

To make this capability available at the command prompt without need for a script file, create a shell function using the following command:

```
tar2() { files=("$@"); for i in "${!files[@]}"; do [ -e "${files[i]}" ] || unset files[i]; done; tar -czvf config.tar.gz "${files[@]}"; }
```

To run this:

```
tar2 abc file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml
```

To make this function definition permanent, add it to your `~/.bashrc` file.

#### Alternative: hard-coding the file names

```
files=(file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml)
for i in "${!files[@]}"
do
    [ -e "${files[i]}" ] || unset files[i]
done
tar -czvf config.tar.gz "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: _"Can't take files as command line Argument"_  What does that mean?  You used the files as a command line argument for tar.  Why not for a script?

Comment: @Rpds7 If you prefer shell functions, I just added one of those that does the same thing as the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop over your list of files to be added in archive and check fo their existence. Note that you will need to use `r` (replace) or `u` (update) mode in uncompressed archive.

```
for f in file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml; do
   [[ -f $f ]] && tar rvf config.tar "$f"
done

# compress the tar file
gzip config.tar
```